# Jquery Datatables Ajax method cell alignment

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, datatables

I am displaying the database table values using data tables. I am doing this using the ajax method. Here is the code

```
$('#example1').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "filename.php",
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

            } );
```

The output of the filename.php is

```
{ "aaData": [["1","<input type='checkbox' name='user'>&nbsp;Test Name","Leader","35"]] }
```

The html code is

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display tablehead" id="example1">
              <thead>
                  <tr class="colhead newbg">
                    <th width="17" align="center">No</th>
                    <th width="194" align="left">User</th>
                    <th width="56" align="left">Role</th>
                    <th width="31" align="right">AGE</th>  
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
              </table>
```

In the above html you can see the first column is center aligned and the next two columns are left aligned and the last one is right aligned. But in the data out put all are center aligned. I tried to use the following

```
{ "aaData": [["<div align='center'>1</div>","<div align='left'><input type='checkbox' name='user'>&nbsp;Test Name</div>","<div align='center'>Leader</div>","<div align='right'>35</div>"]] }
```

Now i got the correct display but while sorting by age it is not correct. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should do something like (use [aoColumns](http://datatables.net/usage/columns)):

```
$('#example1').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "filename.php",
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [ 
                        {"sClass": "center"},
                        {"sClass": "left"},
                        {"sClass": "left"},
                        {"sClass": "right"},

            } );
```

And then define the correct CSS classes

```
.right{
  align: right;
}

.left{
  align: left;
}

.center{
  align: center;
}
```

In this way datatables handles appending the classes to the elements and the sorting works correctly. Of course use the first JSON

Comment: Great. I will try this one and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @Vasanthan.R.P i also posted a link where you can find the docs for aoColumns

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append DIV elements to TABLE body!
You have to create new TR element change all DIV's to TD and then append them to TR element ant then append TR element to TABLE body.

**UPDATE** DIV element has no attribute align, you have to use CSS for this.

Comment: as per data tables these elements will be placed inside tds automatically i hope. So i need a way to align them. Thanks

Comment: he can do that, but if he does that sorting won't work (unless he strips out the html. I think you can use classes to do what he want through datatables API

Answer (score 0):

> Now i got the correct display but while sorting by age it is not correct. Please help. Thanks

As you have HMTL in that column, DataTables will automatically detect it as type 'string' and sort it accordingly. If you want it to sort numerically, stripping the HTML data, use this plug-in: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#numbers_html